# Spell checking in German texts - strange behavior

Tags: user-interface

This questions is about spell checking in German within Mathematica.

I have encountered some strange behaviour of Mathematica's spell-checker. Words within the dictionary are sometimes marked as misspelled even though they are correct (see attached image). This affects other words not just ones containing German umlauts.

[image]

Are there any ideas what one can do to fix this?

Comment: If you highlight the text, right-click, copy as MathML prior to correction, then paste in a text doc, is it different from the spell-corrected MathML?

Comment: @PeterRoberge: This is a good idea, I´ll give it a try asap.

Comment: @PeterRoberge: I tried several approaches. This is the result: In the spell-checking box the word "Zunächst" is (when copied as MathML) `Zun\'e4chst` this holds also for the other entries in this box. In the notebook it is the same, but the output has the form: `Zun&#228;chst`, but 228 decimal is an e4 in hex, so this should not be the problem. This misbehavior can be reproduced...

Comment: is it still `Zun\'e4chst` after it is spell corrected?

Comment: @PeterRoberge: Sorry for the delay in commenting - but I´m actually on a longer trip and have not always time to respond. If I let the word being corrected... nothing changes and in a second run it is again detected as "false". It stays to be `Zun&#228;chst`. Seems like o problem inherent to Mathematica to me.

Comment: Yeah, i think regardless of how it's encoded, this behavior shouldn't exist